# Overpass API dispatcher fails with Address already in use 98

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I've followed the installation instructions on:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/install

Initially everything worked flawless, but I would like to try and use my own custom map, BUT when I killed the dispatcher process nothing works. This is with the original database and not my custom map.

I tried to clean everything and install from scratch, this also worked flawless, but a simple kill on the dispatcher make everything crash from there on.

I currently get the error message when I try to start the dispatcher:
File_Error Address already in use 98 /srv/osm3s/db_dir//osm3s_v0.7.3_osm_base Dispatcher_Server::4

Looking at netstat there's no process using port 98. Restarting the entire server does not make it work. There is no lock file in /dev/shm.

What to do? I do not wish to clean and install everything every time I kill the dispatcher.

Comment: Tried this morning after a nights waiting, no luck. Cleaning the database however seems to fix the issue. So rm -rf * the database directory and populating the entire database seems to do the job. I'll try and compare directories before and after...

Comment: Seems to be a lock in both /dev/shm/ and the database directory. An empty file osm_... is stored in the database directory which locks the process. Removing just those two files (database dir and /dev/shm/) gets the dispatcher up and running again.

Answer (score 8):

Seems to be a lock in both /dev/shm/ and the database directory. An empty file osm_... is stored in the database directory which locks the process. Removing just those two files (database dir and /dev/shm/) gets the dispatcher up and running again.

Comment: Deleting only the osm file did the job for me. Thanks.

Comment: The proper way to stop the dispatcher is via the command line parameter --terminate. Don't just kill the dispatcher process!