# error for area search in own overpass api server

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

How to solve the error when i pass **area param**.
Installed osm-3s_v0.7.53 in a server and able to make request. 
But if i try to make request with **area** then i ma getting the following error

Error: runtime error: open64: 111 Connection refused /home/osm-3s_v0.7.53/bin/db//osm3s_v0.7.53_areas Unix_Socket::7

example query

```
[timeout:25];
area[name="france"];
( node[name="starbucks"];
  way[name="starbucks"];
  rel[name="starbucks"]; 
  );
out center;
```

but if i try

```
[timeout:25];
( node[name="starbucks"];
  way[name="starbucks"];
  rel[name="starbucks"]; 
  );
out center;
```

it gets a valid xml for default area

Please help..

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/55713/error-while-search-with-area-in-own-overpass-api-server

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of area syntax is not quite correct, as well as the spelling of France and Starbucks does not fit the data in OpenStreetMap. The query should look like this:

```
[timeout:600];
area[name="France"]["ISO3166-1"="FR"]->.france;
( node(area.france)[name~"Starbucks"];
  way(area.france)[name~"Starbucks"];
  rel(area.france)[name~"Starbucks"]; 
);
out center;
```

Also, you must start another `dispatcher` process on your own server for **areas**, as well as triggering a dedicated process of creating areas. Please read this up in the Overpass API installation documentation, it describes every step you need to follow.

My recommendation is to get familiar with the syntax on one of the public instances first, and only then start chasing issues on your own instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, i have already tried the area creation step (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Installation#Area_creation) as explained in the docs.

only case was i was not able to do cp -pR "../rules" $DB_DIR as i was not having the rules folder. So i created a rules folder. Please correct me if i am wrong.
Also i have run the following despatcher for **area
nohup osm-3s_v0.7.53/bin/dispatcher --areas --db-dir=osm-3s_v0.7.53/bin/db/ &
But didn't seems like working. i know its strange because i tried googling this error and was unsuccessful in getting a result.

Comment: Please follow up this issue on the Overpass API developers mailing list as it is better suited for this kind of discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. For the are query to work fine

```
dispatcher --areas
```

was not starting and running even after run the command to start this dispatcher. That was due to a socket error. i solved that error by following this link [Overpass API dispatcher fails with Address already in use 98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525795/overpass-api-dispatcher-fails-with-address-already-in-use-98)

NOTE: Before you do the above step run

```
osm-3s_v0.7.53/bin/dispatcher --terminate
```

One think keep in mind if you run the dispatcher with nohup try to add

```
& tail -f nohup.out
```

so that it will help to see if there is an error. 
Mainly the 2 dispatcher --osm-base AND --area should be running always for efficient response from the overpass API installed in your own server.